Is the product of reductive algebraic groups reductive?
I know some cases in which the product of reductive algebraic groups is reductive. For example, $\text{GL}_n\times\text{GL}_m$ is known to be reductive. A product of algebraic tori $T\times T'$ must be too, given that the product of tori is a tori. Also, since we have an isogeny $\mathbb{G}_{\text{m}}\times\text{SL}_2\to\text{GL}_2$, this product must be reductive too.
Is this true in general for any product of reductive groups? Is it true for the product $\mathbb{G}_{\text{m}}\times\text{SL}_2\times\text{SL}_2$?
The last case should be equivalent to showing that $\text{GL}_2\times\text{SL}_2$ is reductive (by the obvious isogeny).

For characteristic 0, being reductive is equivalent to being linearly reductive. The product of linearly reductive algebraic groups is linearly reductive. See 1 and 2.
